# Using stmx with lparallel future in common-lisp

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, common-lisp, stm

I'm trying to use [stmx](https://github.com/cosmos72/stmx) inside the [lparallel](https://github.com/lmj/lparallel) infrastructure.

This simple snippet raises an exception:

```
(ql:quickload :stmx)
(ql:quickload :lparallel)

(setf lparallel:*kernel* (lparallel:make-kernel 4))

(lparallel:future
  (stmx:atomic (format t "~a ~%" "it works")))
```

```
Unhandled SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "lparallel" RUNNING {1003F8F073}>:
  STMX internal error!
  stmx:*current-thread* contains a stale value:
   found #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004DC01F3}>
   expecting #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "lparallel" RUNNING {1003F8F073}>
Typical cause is:
   new threads were created with implementation-specific functions,
   as for example (sb-thread:make-thread) or (mp:process-run-function),
   that do not apply thread-local bindings stored in
   bordeaux-threads:*default-special-bindings*
Solution:
   use (bordeaux-threads:make-thread) instead.
```

The problem is obvious: it seems that `lparallel` starts a native sbcl thread, while stmx relies on `bordeaux-threads` to function correctly.

And indeed, this one fixes an error (though it is a total nonsence):

```
(lparallel:future
  (bt:make-thread
   (lambda ()
     (stmx:atomic (format t "~a ~%" "it works")))))
```

The question is: how to make lparallel spawn bordeaux-threads? is it even possible? or is there another workaround?

**Update**

following @Svante's proposal i've tried to bind `stmx.lang:*current-thread*` to actual lparallel current thread, and surprisingly it works:

```
(defmacro lpar-atomic (&body body)
  `(let ((stmx.lang:*current-thread* (lparallel.thread-util:current-thread)))
     (stmx:atomic ,@body)))

(lparallel:future
  (lpar-atomic (format t "~a ~%" "it works!")))
```

It seems to be a workaround, still it is kind of ugly. If someone has an idea how to do it in general, i'd be glad. Otherwise we probably need to 'fix' stmx somehow )

Comment: I am a bit confused, because looking at the source it seems that lparallel is already using bordeaux-threads.

Comment: @Svante , yes i also thought i saw it somewhere.. But it works this way.. first i thought it could be related to sly mrepl, but `sbcl --load ./some.lisp --disable-debugger` acts the same. I think i have the latest versions from quicklisp (2021-08-07), sbcl 2.1.9

Comment: I think this might be an issue in stmx.  It never re-binds its `*current-thread*` - maybe you need to re-bind it yourself?

Comment: @Svante,  hmm.. i will try to do it later in the evening. Does it look like a library bug to you?

Comment: Not sure, Maybe ask there?